# Showing $\lim\frac{\left| a_{n+1} z^{n+1} \right|}{\left| a_n z^n \right|} = |z| \lim \frac{ a_{n+1} }{ a_n }$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $\sum a_n z^n$ be a complex power series.  I've seen it asserted without explanation in a text that

$$
\lim\frac{\left| a_{n+1} z^{n+1} \right|}{\left| a_n z^n \right|} = |z| \lim \frac{ a_{n+1}  }{ a_n  } 
$$

This is not an obvious equality to me.  How is it being derived?

Comment: You can cancel $z^n$ (or $\lvert z\rvert^n$) from the quotient, and pull the constant $\lvert z\rvert$ out of the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim\frac{|a_{n+1}z^{n+1}|}{|a_nz^n|}=\lim\frac{|a_{n+1}||z^{n+1}|}{|a_n||z^n|}=\lim\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\left|\frac{z^{n+1}}{z^n}\right|=\lim\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}|z|=|z|\lim\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}$$